# Python: parse XML with utf-8 (cyrillic) as string

Tags: python, xml, string, utf-8, jupyter

I need to read xml file as a string (not to parse it). Problem is, it is all in Cyrillic, and I failed reading (or, at least, printing) the string in a good way.

my attempts:

```
with open (path, "r" ) as myfile:
    return myfile.read().replace('\n', '')


with open (path, "r" ) as myfile:
     return unicode(myfile.read().replace('\n', ''),encoding='utf8')
```

both work, and I've been able to operate on string in first case - but still cannot print it

UPDATE

It looks like I pointed in the wrong direction with this problem: I use Jupyther notebooks, so the same issue even with "ordinal" cases:

```
import re

text = '<p id="p755">После Смоленска Наполеон'

m = re.search('(?:<p.*>)(.*)', text)
if m:
    found = m.group(1)

found
'\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xa1\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 \xd0\x9d\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd'
```

Comment: I bet you're mixing up some encoding and unicode. Have you tried this in Python 3? It doesn't let you confuse things as easily as 2.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.
Unfortunately, I have this XML as is :-(

Comment: Actually It looks like I pointed in the wrong direction: I use Jupyter Notebooks here, so even "normal" use has the same result

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to print?

Comment: it prints unparsed string: '\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xa1\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 \xd0\x9d\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd'